# Is the establishment of entanglement inevitable with the passage of time?

Tags: entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

Derivation of the Lindblad master equation starts with the assumption that at an initial time $t=0$, the total density matrix is the product of the density matrices of the system $\rho_S$ and that of the environment $\rho_E$ i.e. $$\rho_{\rm tot}(0)=\rho_S(0)\otimes\rho_E(0)\tag{1}$$

**Question** If we start with such a factorizable density matrix (of the form Eq.$(1)$), is it inevitable that entanglement will be established between system and environment at $t>0$ irrespective of the interaction Hamiltonian that couples the system and environment? Can we think of a situation where the interaction Hamiltonian such that no entanglement is ever produced under time development?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is inevitable that entanglement will emerge at $t>0$ if you want your system to evolve in a non-trivial way. This is due to the fact that, if the action of the bath on the system is not trivial, it means that the system-environment interaction is non-local and generates entanglement. Although for Markovian systems the amount of correlations built up at each time-step are neglected during the computation of the master equation, they still exist, e.g. have a look at the nice discussion in this [reference](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/12/11/113032): if the bath is large but finite, the emergence of correlations is clearly visible.

Still, it may happen that the system-environment interaction has no effect on a certain subspace of the Hilbert space of the system. This is the case of the [decoherence-free subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoherence-free_subspaces). If the initial state of the system belongs to a decoherence-free subspace, then its dynamics will be decoupled from the environment one and no entanglement will arise.

Comment: Hi! Minor comment: consider using the DOI when linking to papers published in journals (linking to `https://doi.org/...`), to avoid possible [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) in the future. It would also be a good idea to give full bibliographic references (author, title, journal, volume ...). Cf. various meta discussions: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/149907, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4820/149907.